# http header is alway empty in cross site request

Tags: node.js, express, http, cookies

I want to set cookie in react nodejs pair but server is not sending cookie even not sending Header.

**Note: Nodejs server in react origin are different**

```
app.use(morgan("short"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://192.168.43.xxx:5173");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, DELETE");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
  next();
});

app.post("/", (req, res) => {
  res.cookie("Access-token", "my very secret token", {
    httpOnly: true,
    maxAge: 1000 * 3600,
    secure: true,
    sameSite: "strict",
  });
  res.setHeader("Any-Header", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX");
  res.send({ message: "OK" });
});
```

And my client side code is

```
const handleSet = async () => {
    var response = await fetch("http://192.168.43.xxx:5000/", {
      method: "POST",
      credentials: "include",
    });

    const headers = response.headers;
    console.log(headers);

    const body = await response.json();
    console.log({ headers, body });
    setOutput(JSON.stringify(headers, body));
  };
```

i am using it in side react component.

I need a simple explanation and solution please.

Comment: You write: _even not sending Header_. What header are you referring to? Besides, be aware that browsers reject attempts to set a cookie marked `Secure` from an insecure origin (e.g. an origin that has `http` as its scheme). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#restrict_access_to_cookies: _Insecure sites [sic] (with `http:` in the URL) can't set cookies with the `Secure` attribute_.

Comment: i was unable to set cookie.

Comment: Not surprising. Have you read and understood my comment?

Comment: i have tried without secure tag, but it still not working

Comment: Is the `Set-Cookie` header present in the response, at least?

Comment: Actually i am trying to a authontication system in react but ended up in here. unable to set cookie.

Comment: Nothing, header is a empty, i logged header in console.

Comment: You won't see any `Set-Cookie` response header in the console, because that header is ["invisible" to JavaScript running in the client](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-response-header-name). Look in your browser's Network tab instead.

Comment: Okay, i will check it out tomorrow,but what about other headers? Why other headers are not printing in the console?

Comment: Because the server needs to explicitly tell the browser that the client is allowed to read the response headers. That's where [`Access-Control-Expose-Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers) comes in.